# Unable to use Cmd+I shortcut of Copilot in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

Till yesterday, I was able to use the shortcut Cmd+I for copilot in VS Code, but now I am unable to use these copilot shortcuts (don't know if VS-Code is recently updated).
Before:
[image: Before]

But Now on Clicking Cmd+I.
[image: Now on clicking Cmd+I]

But inline recommendation is working fine
[image: Copilot Subscription not expired]

Copilot Subscription not expired. Tried logging out and in again, but same problem keeps happening.

Comment: VS Code recently released 1.86.0. But I don't see any recent in the default keybinding for starting inline chat. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/7cc042767b50448d36367e6061f43eea2049c685/src/vs/workbench/contrib/inlineChat/browser/inlineChatActions.ts#L50) and follow the git blame.

Maybe something in the when clause isn't matching? `"when": "editorFocus && inlineChatHasProvider && !editorReadonly"`

Comment: if you search in your keyboard shortcut editor for "`"ctrl+i"`", do you see the default keybinding for starting inline chat?